# Splitting Sensenet content repository into multiple databases

Tags: sensenet

Is there a way of splitting a Content repository into multiple databases? There is a great chance I'll have TBs of data, maybe even tens of TBs of data. Maintaining database bigger than 1 TB becomes an issue, so I can't imagine dealing with a bigger database. I've considered using Filestream, but having multiple databases would be much more viable solution.

If not, is there at least a way of having several repositories contained in a single web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (as of version 7.2) sensenet requires a central database to connect to, you cannot split that into multiple parts.

There is the [blob storage](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/blob-provider) feature however that lets you store binaries **outside of the main metadata database**. You choose a blob storage implementation (e.g. the [MongoDb blob provider](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/mongodb-provider/)), install it and you can start uploading files to sensenet. Binaries above a certain (configured) size will go to the external provider.

You'll have to take care of the backup of the blob storage though, because that is different for every db provider. At least the size of the metadata db will be significantly lower.